# Trying to learn basic file manipulation in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the hang of working with files in `C++`. I'm trying to read from one file and make another file with the same contents. I've succeeded to a point where I can get the first line of my file to get copied but not the rest. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    string line;
    ofstream writeFile;
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("students.txt");
    if (readFile.is_open()){
        while (getline (readFile, line)){
            writeFile.open("copytext.txt");
            writeFile << line;
            writeFile << line;
            writeFile << line;
            writeFile << line;
        }
    }
    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try opening the output file only once, perhaps?

Comment: And probably shouldn't try to write 4 times either...

Comment: sorry, the write times was my attempt at getting more lines in the file. botfh of the files i'm trying to open are different.

Comment: So, did you try moving the `writefile.open` out of the loop?

Comment: To explain Mats first point... move the `writeFile.open` before the `while (getline` loop, so it only executes once.  If you keep re-opening the file, you keep writing lines at the start, rather than appending to the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, if you don't specify a flag, the `openmode` is going to be `write`. This will **destroy** the contents of the file if it already exists.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream of("test.txt"); // close() implicitly called by destructor
}
```

```
> echo "hello" > test.txt
> cat test.txt
hello
> g++ test.cpp
> ./a.out
> cat test.txt
```

Oops!

You should obviously move it outside the loop. By the way, you don't need to call `open` or `close` explicitly, because the constructors and destructors will call those respectively. The stream objects will also be implicitly convertible to bool (returning false if there's an error in the stream), making `is_open` redundant.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    string line;
    ifstream readFile("students.txt");
    ofstream writeFile("copytext.txt");

    if (readFile && writeFile){
        while (getline (readFile, line)) {
            writeFile << line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright guys, thanks a lot for the help! I understand what I did wrong now. Sucks I got downvoted for trying to learn. Guess cuz I'm a newb.

Comment: @sickcodeworm Ignore that, it's a good question: full (short) code example and pretty clear description of the problem. That fact the you got several answers is a good hint at that. (As a personal rule, if I'm answering a question, it probably deserves a +1).

Comment: That's awesome. Can you tell me how I can modify this code so that whenever I see a certain character (like a or b or , or " "), how i can make it skip a line in the newly created text?

Comment: @sickcodeworm Clue: [`if (line.find('a') == std::string::npos) ...`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) then there is no `'a'`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/), opening the same file again is impossible and results in failure, as inicated by setting `failbit`. The desired output file should be opened only once.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can rewrite from your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

string line;
ofstream writeFile;
ifstream readFile;
readFile.open("students.txt");
writeFile.open("copytext.txt",std::fstream::out);
if (readFile.is_open()){
while (getline (readFile, line)){

    writeFile << line;


}

}
readFile.close();
writeFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

you can use open mode when open an stream either:  std::fstream::in or  std::fstream::out or std::fstream::app up to your purpose

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

string line;
ofstream writeFile;
ifstream readFile;
readFile.open("students.txt");
writeFile.open("copytext.txt");
if (readFile.is_open()){
    while (getline (readFile, line))
    {       
        writeFile << line << "\n";

    }
}
readFile.close();
writeFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

One of the problems was that you were trying to open "copytext.txt" inside the while loop. You were also trying to write the same text 4 times which was unnecessary.